# PayPal Payment - Do a payment in one step

Tags: paypal, payment, checkout

I have a form where people can order one single item for a fixed amount of money. Here are the steps:

- customer fills out the form
- customer hits submit and proceeds to the review page where he can check his inputs
- in the review form should be a button to pay with paypal (button with own design and text)
- customer hits this button, proceeds to paypal, makes his payment
- after he paid successfully or not he should be redirected to the form on my site where he can see the result of his payment
- wehter his payment succeeded or not he can see a message generated by the form application out of the PayPal return string

I tried it but the only thing I can do is that after he submits the form he logs into PayPal, hits the "continue" button and is redirected to my site where he can review his order again and needs to hit "Pay" again to get his order processed.

So all I want is that the customer does all the inputs and reviews on my site and after that he hits a "Pay" button in my own style and proceeds to PayPal where he pays the order without getting back to my site until the payment is done. Then he should be redirected to my site and receives the appropriate message.

What kind of PayPal function do I need?
Hope this was clear enough. Please let me know if you need further information. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Paypal Express Checkout is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal Express Checkout is what you are looking for, it will solve your problem

Follow the sample and guide:

[Link to Code Sample](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/)

[Link to Paypal Doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have. But what I want is that the customer won't be redirected to my site until the whole payment is done on PayPal. In Express Checkout the user gets redirected to my site after he logged in at PayPal, and then the payment is done after he hits "Pay" on my site.
Is there any way to send the user to PayPal where he pays without the step back to my site?

Comment: Then you need to use Adaptive Payment method, or also have a look at Button Manager
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/product-info/

Comment: Is doDirectPayment limited to credit card payment or may I use it with every single payment operation such as login and pay the amount in the paymentrequest_0_amt ?

Comment: Found the solution. It is as you all told me the Express Checkout and I can skip the review page after PayPal login by adding the "&useraction=commit" parameter to the PayPal URL.
Thank you all. And I think I should learn to read documentations instead of bothering on stackoverflow.com.