# Regarding PayPal Pro payment

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, paypal, payment-gateway

Well I have a website for which I have implemented PayPal Pro's `dodirectpayment` (For accepting payment using credit/debit card)

Now I want to move my code live but under account eligibility there is a message saying:

*"Direct credit card processing is not available for you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing for your country but your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing."*

I have an Australian PayPal account. I also read some PayPal documentation saying PayPal Pro is only available for UK and Canada. Can someone suggest the alternate of this or how to resolve this problem?

Comment: use express checkout or adaptive payment via paypal
Check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135151/paypal-payment-do-a-payment-in-one-step/24135224#24135224

Comment: Is express checkout work for credit card/debit card payment for non UK/Canadians.? Is there is any way to sort out the problem of paypal pro for NON UK/Canadians.

Comment: I hope so you need to check once

Comment: do upvote if the solution helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

PayPal offers several hosted solutions in [Australia](https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/sell-online). If you require direct credit card processing read about Payflow. The [Payflow Gateway](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#payflow-gateway) SDKs should help you get started. Also, you can find php SDK and code samples [here](http://ccaples.com/index.php/misc/tools-and-stuff/downloads).